# TestFlight crashes: you don't have permission to save the file on iOS build

Tags: ios, angular, macos, nativescript, testflight

I have an iOS application in appstore connect built with Nativescript + Angular. I've tested it in Xcode simulator and on a physical device successfully. Unfortunately, I can't get it on Testflight to send to testers. Upon downloading my app, testers see the splash screen and then an immediate crash with the following:

`

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “assets” in the folder “app”.

createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError@[native code]

getFile@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system-access.js:51:97

getFile@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.js:352:42

loadFile@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-ngx-fonticon/services/fonticon.service.js:46:70

loadFiles@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-ngx-fonticon/services/fonticon.service.js:32:31

loadCss@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-ngx-fonticon/services/fonticon.service.js:38:18

TNSFontIconService@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-ngx-fonticon/services/fonticon.service.js:12:21

_createClass@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17811:32

_createProviderInstance@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17783:42

initNgModule@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17716:59

NgModuleRef_@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:18443:25

createNgModuleRef@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:18432:32

file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:14656:53

onInvoke@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:14194:43

run@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:138:49

run@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:138:49

file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:883:37

runTask@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:188:57

drainMicroTaskQueue@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:595:42

file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:173:44

notify@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:31

[native code]

notifyAppStarted@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:140:36

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:132:30

[native code]

onReceive@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:30:32

UIApplicationMain@[native code]

start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:273:26

run@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:301:10

bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:187:26

bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:105:38

bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:89:26

anonymous@file:///app/main.js:10:57

evaluate@[native code]

moduleEvaluation@[native code]

promiseReactionJob@[native code]`
```

Does this look familiar to anyone? I thought maybe the root folder didn't have the right permissions, so I changed those to Read/Write for all user groups and still got the same error. The users that received these emails are part of these groups, so am I missing something about how to give them permission?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save any file to current app directory? It's readonly in iOS, you must use documents directory.

Comment: well i assume testflight is saving some files to the device to run the app right?